# Berkeley DB cannot set value with different Dbt initialization

Tags: c++, linux, database, dbt, berkeley-db

The only difference of the code is the initialisation of data. This works:

```
        Dbt key, data(&b, sizeof(int));
        key.set_data(&a);
        key.set_ulen(sizeof(int));
        data.set_flags(DB_DBT_USERMEM);
```

but this doesn't:

```
        Dbt key, data;
        key.set_data(&a);
        key.set_ulen(sizeof(int));
        data.set_data(&b);
        data.set_ulen(sizeof(int));
        data.set_flags(DB_DBT_USERMEM);
```

I read to document in https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17076_04/html/api_reference/CXX/dbt.html and I didn't see differences of these two ways. It's confusing.

The complete code and result are shown below:

```
$ cat db.cpp

#include <db.h>
#include <db_cxx.h>
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
        Db db(NULL, 0);
        u_int32_t oFlags = DB_CREATE | DB_TRUNCATE;
        try {
            db.open(NULL, "test.db", NULL, DB_HASH, oFlags, 0);
        } catch (DbException &e) {
            cout << "DbException" << endl;
        } catch (std::exception &e) {

        }
        int a = 5, b = 6, c = 0, result[1]= {-1};
        Dbt key, data(&b, sizeof(int));
        key.set_data(&a);
        key.set_ulen(sizeof(int));
        data.set_flags(DB_DBT_USERMEM);
        cout << (db.get(NULL, &key, &data, 0) == DB_NOTFOUND) << endl;
        cout << c << endl;
        db.put(NULL, &key, &data, 0);
        key.set_data(&a);
        data.set_data(result);
        data.set_ulen(sizeof(int));
        cout << (db.get(NULL, &key, &data, 0) )<< endl;
        cout << *((int *) data.get_data()) << endl;
        cout << result[0] << endl;
        return 0;
}

$ rm test.db ; g++ db.cpp -ldb_cxx-5.1; ./a.out
1
0
0
6
6

$ cat db.cpp

#include <db.h>
#include <db_cxx.h>
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
        Db db(NULL, 0);
        u_int32_t oFlags = DB_CREATE | DB_TRUNCATE;
        try {
            db.open(NULL, "test.db", NULL, DB_HASH, oFlags, 0);
        } catch (DbException &e) {
            cout << "DbException" << endl;
        } catch (std::exception &e) {

        }
        int a = 5, b = 6, c = 0, result[1]= {-1};
        Dbt key, data;
        key.set_data(&a);
        key.set_ulen(sizeof(int));
        data.set_data(&b);
        data.set_ulen(sizeof(int));
        data.set_flags(DB_DBT_USERMEM);
        cout << (db.get(NULL, &key, &data, 0) == DB_NOTFOUND) << endl;
        cout << c << endl;
        db.put(NULL, &key, &data, 0);
        key.set_data(&a);
        data.set_data(result);
        data.set_ulen(sizeof(int));
        cout << (db.get(NULL, &key, &data, 0) )<< endl;
        cout << *((int *) data.get_data()) << endl;
        cout << result[0] << endl;
        return 0;
}

$ rm test.db ; g++ db.cpp -ldb_cxx-5.1; ./a.out
1
0
0
-1
-1
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `Dbt.set_size()`.  `Dbt.set_ulen()` only sets the allocation size of the memory pointed to by `Dbt.data`.  `Dbt.size` has the actual used length of either your key or your data.  Adding those calls to your second example should make it work:

```
    Dbt key, data;
    key.set_data(&a);
    key.set_ulen(sizeof(int));
    key.set_size(sizeof(int));
    data.set_data(&b);
    data.set_ulen(sizeof(int));
    data.set_size(sizeof(int));
    data.set_flags(DB_DBT_USERMEM);
```

As to why the `Dbt key` is working at all for you without `set_size`, I'm not at all sure.  Perhaps you're getting lucky with uninitialized data on the stack?  If you care to find out, you could print out the value of `key.size`.

As a point of clarity, you don't need to set `ulen` ahead of a `put()`.  It only needs to be set before you do a `get()` to let BDB know how much memory it has to read the data into.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You've been really helpful.